# c++ runtime error with random_shuffle of vector in a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, blackjack

I am trying to code a game of Blackjack. I have been self-learning C++ in my spare time, and this is my first time posting on any website about programming.

I have been looking up the answers to my problems as I go along, and have learned quite a lot.. but this problem has completely baffled me. I fear that I am approaching the task completely wrong, and hopefully you can help me with this.

I have a Card class, and a Deck class that holds a vector of 52 Cards. The vector is a private member of Deck class, and I fear this is my problem?

When I add the random_shuffle line to my code, it compiles fine but then the console window crashes (Windows 7 x64, code::blocks, c++). I can't work out what I am doing wrong. I call the vector random access iterators begin() and end()...

**deck.h**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/** Card Class */
class Card
{
public:
/** Constructor prototypes */
//Card(); //default constructor
Card(int s, int r) : suit(s), rank(r) {} 

/** GET function prototypes */
int getRank(); // returns card number as int
string getSuit(); // returns the suit in a string

private:
int rank;
int suit;
} ;

/** Deck class */
class Deck
{
public:
Deck();
vector <Card> get_deck() { return deck; };

private:
vector<Card> deck;
};

#endif // DECK_H
```

**deck.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "deck.h"

using namespace std;

/** Deck ctor to initialise deck */
Deck::Deck()
{
for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
{
    for(int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++)
    {
        deck.push_back(Card(suit,rank));
    }
}

}

/** Functions to GET rank and suit */
// Function to get rank as int
int Card::getRank()
{
return rank;
}

// Function to get suit as string
string Card::getSuit()
{
switch(suit)
{
    case 0:
    return "Diamonds";

    case 1:
    return "Hearts";

    case 2:
    return "Clubs";

    case 3:
    return "Spades";

    default:
    return "Error";
}
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime> // time()
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "deck.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

Deck mydeck;

random_shuffle( mydeck.get_deck().begin(), mydeck.get_deck().end() );

// Loop to iterate through deck of cards
for(int i = 0; i<52; i++)
{
    cout << mydeck.get_deck()[i].getRank() << " of " << mydeck.get_deck()[i].getSuit() << endl;
}

// Display size of deck
//cout << endl << "The size of deck is: " << mydeck.get_deck().size() << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Any help or words of wisdom will be much appreciated, and I hope I formatted everything right...

Many Thanks

Dan

Comment: +1 for posting compilable code that reproduces the problem, -1 for not narrowing it down. So 0.

Comment: Your Deck class is little more than a [useless] wrapper around a vector of Cards.  It seems to me that a Deck class should have its own shuffle method, i.e. `void Deck::Shuffle() { random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end()); }` -- along with other methods such as getting the top card, or the bottom card, or getting a random card from the deck.  Then I would get rid of your `get_deck()` method.

Comment: @StarPilot That's a link to this page.

Comment: LOL. Sorry about that. Grabbed the wrong window's URL. Just one of those days.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In future I will narrow down the code to where my problem is... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This accessor method:

```
vector <Card> get_deck() { return deck; };
```

Returns a *copy* of the vector of cards.  So when you call it twice, you get two different copies, and the `begin()` of the first copy doesn't match up with the `end()` of the second copy, so it crashes.

To fix it, you should return the array *by reference* so that a copy is not made:

```
vector <Card>& get_deck() { return deck; }  // no semicolon needed here
//           ^
//           |
//    this is a reference
```

However, this allows the caller to modify the internal array, which is generally a bad idea.  To avoid this, you should return it by `const` reference:

```
const vector <Card>& get_deck() { return deck; }
```

But if you do that, then `std::random_shuffle` can't modify the array.  So to fix that, the ideal solution would be to add a class method to the `Deck` class which calls `random_shuffle` on itself.

Comment: Another option would be to implement the shuffle in the Deck class itself.

Comment: @Will This is a much better idea.

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining where I was going wrong and helping me with the solution. It all makes sense now and I can see now the process of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning `vector<Card>&` from `get_deck()`. In the posted code you are making two separate copies and returning those.

When `random_shuffle` tries to do its job it therefore has iterators pointing into two different vectors.

As @Will points out in comments to another answer, you would be better off preserving encapsulation by implementing a method `void Deck::shuffle()` which calls `random_shuffle` on the member `deck` and not expose `deck` at all.

Comment: How can I cout loop through the actual cards in the vector and not a copy of the vector? I guess it is with a member function of Deck like `void Deck::displayCard()` which will then access the private variable (the vector deck)?